# Here i'm trying to convert a normal folder to zip folder,but it is showing invalid method declaration

Tags: java

```
public class foldertoZip {    
List<String> fileList;
private static final String OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE = "Folder.zip";
private static final String SOURCE_FOLDER = "C:\\Users\\wahidbasha\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EpubtoZip\\build\\web\\2012LH";      //SourceFolder path

zipFIle() {
    fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    zipFIle appZip = new zipFIle();
    appZip.generateFileList(new File(SOURCE_FOLDER));
    appZip.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
}

public void zipIt(String zipFile) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    String source = "";
    try {
        try {
            source = SOURCE_FOLDER.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, SOURCE_FOLDER.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            source = SOURCE_FOLDER;
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + zipFile);

        for (String file : this.fileList) {

            System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);

            FileInputStream in =
                    new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file);

            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
        }

        zos.closeEntry();
        //remember close it
        zos.close();

        System.out.println("Folder successfully compressed");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}

public void generateFileList(File node) {

    //add file only
    if (node.isFile()) {
        fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.toString()));

    }

    if (node.isDirectory()) {
        String[] subNote = node.list();
        for (String filename : subNote) {
            generateFileList(new File(node, filename));
        }
    }

}

private String generateZipEntry(String file) {
    return file.substring(SOURCE_FOLDER.length() + 1, file.length());
}   
}
```

Here i'm converting all folders of 2012LH(which contains multiple folder(eg A,B,C) and files inside A,B,C(like a,b,c,d,e)) into zip folder i.e.,Folder.zip; but it is showing invalid method declaration at zipFIle() ,can any body help me how to do this,thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that `zipFile` declaration is valid? Java method signatures start with a return type.

Comment: You already have a good answer at your other question, why ask again?

Comment: @ amjad: 1. It is **not cool** to post duplicates of your questions. 2. Use standard capitalization when asking people to help you with your Java code (class names in initially-capped CamelCase, method names in initially-lower-case camelCase). You can do whatever you like in your own code; as soon as you're asking others to read it, show the courtesy of making it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like "public class foldertoZip"  needs to be changed to "public class zipFIle" and that should allow the zipFIle() method as constructor and it should go thru fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a constructor. You must match class names to constructor names:

```
public foldertoZip() {
    fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foldertoZip appZip = new foldertoZip();
    appZip.generateFileList(new File(SOURCE_FOLDER));
    appZip.zipIt(OUTPUT_ZIP_FILE);
}
```

Anyway, I recommend that you name classes with capital letters (e.g. `FolderToZipProcessor`) next time.